# how to change tooltip value in ngbTooltip in angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbTooltip for my form. Currently I need to change my tooltip text according to status.

There are two status in my form. My status are

1. element.checkinStatus = "pending"
2. element.checkinStatus = "approved"

according to above status i need to change the tooltip content. I tried. But its not working.

```
 <button mat-stroked-button type="button" class="action-btn"
                                    ngbTooltip="{'PENDING' : element.checkinStatus=='pending','APPROVED' : element.checkinStatus=='approved'}"
                                    (click)="editCheckIn('edit',element)">
                                    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                                </button>
```

how do this dynamically. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to below way

```
 [ngbTooltip]="{{element.checkinStatus=='pending' ? 'PENDING' : element.checkinStatus=='approved' ? 'APPROVED' : ''}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

```
[ngbTooltip]="element.checkinStatus | uppercase"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it